# URL Parameter Passing with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to visit a page like...

```
http://mysitelocaltion/user_name/user_id
```

This is just a virtual link, I have used a .htaccess -rewrite rule to internally pass "user_name" and "use_id" as get parameters for my actual page.

How do I achieve the same in Laravel?

**Update:**
This shall help (documentation)

```
Route::get('user/(:any)/task/(:num)', function ($username, $task_number) {
    // $username will be replaced by the value of (:any)
    // $task_number will be replaced by the integer in place of (:num)
    $data = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'task' => $task_number
    );
    return View::make('tasks.for_user', $data);
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Route::get('(:any)/(:any)', function($user_name, $user_id) {
    echo $user_name;
});
```

Great to see you using Laravel!

Comment: These are basic questions, might I suggest you check out my tutorials at http://daylerees.com :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following in your route

```
Route::get('user_name/{user_id}', 'YourControllerName@method_name');
```

In your controller you can access the value as follows

```
public function method_name(Request $request, $user_id){
    echo $user_id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    return view('view_name')->with('user', $user);
}
```